# Fill duedate field based on value of terms field

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Is it possible to fill the `duedate` field based on the `terms` field? For example, I have a date in the `duedate` field, but I want to extend it based on the `terms` field. How can I do it? Through Suitescript or workflow?

The code is incomplete because I don’t know if I’m on the right path.
(NB: It is a user event)

```
function beforeLoad(context) {
    
}

function beforeSubmit(context) {
    
}

function afterSubmit(context) {
   var dataEntrega = context.currentRecord

   currentRecordRecord.getValue({
       fieldId: 'duedate'
   })

   var dataCondicoes = context.currentRecord

   currentRecord.getValue({
       fieldId: 'terms'
   })

   

}

return {
    beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
    beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
    afterSubmit: afterSubmit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work.  Depending on your needs I recommend adding some limitations to when this logic is executed. For example you can only execute based on if the transaction/record mode is create/copy (decide if you want to include edit or not).  You can also check the status of the transaction, and only execute if the status is not partially paid/paid in full...

```
function afterSubmit(context) {

  //load record
  var curRec = context.newRecord; //can substitute "context.oldRecord", or "currentRecord.get();"

  //get current due date
  var transDueDate = curRec.getValue({fieldId: 'duedate'});

  //get the terms, this will likely come as an internal id. use getText if you want the text.
  var transTerms = curRec.getValue({fieldId: 'terms'});

  //empty string to hold terms as a number of days
  var addtlDays;

  //transform the internal id to terms as a number of days
  switch (transTerms){
    case 1: // Ex: 1 = internal id for term "Net 15"
      addtlDays = 15;
      break;

    case 2: // Ex: 2 = internal id for term "Net 30"
      addtlDays = 30;
      break;

    //add additional case statements as needed

    default:
      addtlDays = 0;
  }

  //calculuate the new due date
  var d = new Date(transDueDate);
  var newDueDate = d.setDate(d.getDate() + addtlDays);

  //set the new due date
  curRec.setValue({
    fieldId: 'duedate',
    value: newDueDate,
    ignoreFieldChange: true //optional, default is false
  });
}
```

Comment: That should help. I may need to make some adjustments on behalf of the company, but I appreciate it a lot

Comment: No problem, best of luck!

Comment: Hi Martha, I had a problem with the code. netsuite gives me this error: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "getValue" of undefined (/SuiteScripts/alter_date_ue.js#23)

Comment: My apologies for the oversight on my part.  "curRec" is not defined since "context.currenRecord" is not a valid parameter for the afterSubmit script type (https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/44547/kw/44547).  I've modified the answer above to reflect using one of the the following to load the current record: "context.newRecord", "context.oldRecord", or currentRecord.get();

Comment: No problem! Thank you again <3

Comment: Hey, Martha, Can you help me? Sorry, I promise it's the last time

Comment: How may I assist?

Comment: netsuite gives me a warning: invalid date value (must be DD/MM/YYYY)

Comment: If the native javascript new Date() and/or setDate() aren't being accepted use the format module to create a netsuite date object.  var newAcceptableDate = format.format({value: newDueDate, type: format.Type.DATE});

Comment: OK! I will try here. Thanks a lot   <3

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to script this?  I believe the due date is calculated based on the terms out of the box, no need for scripting

Comment: Answering a company order, I need the invoice date to be extended according to the customer's payment terms. I was looking to do this with workflow (which I think is an alternative).